# Forward con iptables para puerto de base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, ubuntu, iptables

En nuestra empresa ha surgido la necesidad de redirigir las conexiones de una base de datos en local a una base de datos remota. Las premisas son:

- Ubuntu server
- No podemos modificar el aplicativo para que apunte a la base de datos remota.
- Queremos evitar usar un tunnel ssh.
- La base de datos en local no se puede parar. Escucha por el puerto 5433.

Por lo tanto, deseamos redirigir localhost:5433 a {ip}:5433 con iptables. Hemos hecho algunas pruebas y nos encontramos que seguimos conectando a la base de datos local.

Ejemplo:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 5433 -j DNAT --to 10.250.11.80:5433
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type UNICAST -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

Como no lo hemos conseguido, hemos realizado otras pruebas con puertos diferentes a 5433 y nos ha funcionado:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 5434 -j DNAT --to 10.250.11.80:5433
```

Deducimos que debe algun problema al tener una base de datos en local escuchando por el puerto 5433, seguramente hay alguna mejor forma de resolver esto pero no la hemos encontrado.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: segun veo en las reglas, estas no se aplicarian ya que el output no tocaria esas conexions, es decir no llegarian a pasar a esa etapa.
Creo que el filtrado deberias hacerlo en otras etapas de la coneccion. En caso que continues con el problema lo vemos mas a fondo, pero como ya tiene un buen tiempo la pregunta no se si vale a la pena ahora. Saludos